# Pentaho ETL : Data from 'Table input' to 'Table output'

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pdi

Scenario :

```
 Generate rows -> Table input -> Delay row -> Table output.
```

Generate Rows : (4 copies)

```
   Generate 10 rows.
   Pass the field 'value' with value 1.
```

Table input : (4 copies)

```
   Run for each row and use the value 1 (as where 1 = ?. So no effect).
   insert data from previous step.
   Get the count of a table my_table (select count(*) from...). 
   Field = val_count.
```

Delay row: (4 copies)

```
   1 second delay.
```

Table output: (1 copy)

```
   Insert the val_count to the same table, i.e. my_table.
   commit row = 1.
   truncate table.
```

Database :

```
   Oracle
```

once the transform finish, the my_table filled with the value only 0 (totally 40 zero's). Why the table input not getting the actual row count after the first round of execution (round 2 to 10). or what mistake i did in this design?

[image]

*Pentaho : Kettle - Spoon General Availability Release - 5.3.0.0-213*

*Java : jdk1.8.0_51 (64)*

*Os : Windows 8.1 (64)*

*Oracle : Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production*

**More info added after analysis**

In the four links to the table output, i removed the delay from one link. So i got some what expected. So i removed all the delay and i got the expected result. But i can't able to understand the reason.

Comment: are you sure that query wouldn't just be returning 0 as the result? Try running the transformation in debug mode, it should mention in the logs the query that is actually sent to the DB server.

Comment: Thanks. Just now learning, i don't know the full procedure to debug. But after some analysis, i have edited the question with more information

Comment: can you attach the ktr file? There can be many reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I will attache the file via skydrive account after some time. Did you designed with delay step. Is that working fine for you?. If so i can do some more analysis.

Comment: Attached files : [KTR File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uyIVr9bLqadTZIUEdkSXVzMm8/view?usp=sharing) & [Oracle Table Script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uyIVr9bLqaRHJIQ3hIM19WVHM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: To the ktr file, need to create the oracle connection and map it for both table input and output.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I did not get a notification cos you have not tagged me. What is you requirement? Is there any data in it. This becomes very slow when all the table inputs execute together. If you want a count why do you repeat it in 4 branches. I can redesign this if you tell the correct requirement.